# Strict aliasing in practice

Tags: c, compilation

C11 code like the following is undefined behavior:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct point2d {
  int x, y;
};

struct point3d {
  int x, y, z;
};

typedef struct point2d point2d;
typedef struct point3d point3d;

int foo(point2d *p, point3d *q) {
  p->x = -1;
  p->y = -2;
  q->x = 1;
  q->y = 2;
  q->z = 3;
  return p->x;
}

int main(void) {
  point3d r;
  int n = foo((point2d *) &r, &r);

  printf("%d\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

And indeed, it is:

```
wrc@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -O0 test.c -o test; ./test
1
wrc@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -O3 test.c -o test; ./test
-1
```

The C11 standard says (6.5/7):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

My question is about [this](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/garray.c#L183) kind of technique, where you try to hide information by casting a pointer to a larger struct into a pointer to a smaller struct, that does not contain all members of the larger one.

Here a summary of the relevant struct definitions:

```
struct _GRealArray
{
  guint8 *data;
  guint   len;
  guint   alloc;
  guint   elt_size;
  guint   zero_terminated : 1;
  guint   clear : 1;
  gint    ref_count;
  GDestroyNotify clear_func;
};

struct _GArray
{
  gchar *data;
  guint len;
};

typedef struct _GRealArray GRealArray;
typedef struct _GArray      GArray;
```

Would such a technique already be a violation of the standard? If no: What is the difference? If yes: why doesn't it matter here? Are there some practical guidelines that allow you to *de-facto* violate the standard in this case with no bad consequences (contrary to the `test.c` example above)?

Answer (score 0):

The `Garray` example would be subject to the same rules, if it would stress them, but it seems to be carefully avoiding that.

For user code there can never be aliasing violation between the two types, because, if I see this correctly, the `GRealArray` type is not visible, so all these aliasing problems can't occur in user code with these two types.

For the internal code of the implementation, there seems no point where aliasing can occur for the simple reason that there always is only one array visible in each function. or to say it more directly,

> the aliasing rules only apply if there is potential aliasing.

And even if it would, if that implementation consistently uses the same type for two different pointers that it handles, the compiler still would have to assume that two such pointers can  point to the same object.

BTW, this only answers your direct question not if the behavior of the code that your are pointing to is well defined. This would ask for a deep review of that code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it apparently can't occur, accessing an object with an incompatible type is undefined behavior. Even if the function receives a single pointer of type T, if an incompatible pointer is passed to that function you get ub. In the example OP posted this happens when the pointer is returned `return (GArray*) array;` and then accessed by the callee using the type GArray.

Comment: @2501, yes it does matter. The question that is asked is about aliasing rules and nothing else. Then I also I think that your objection might not apply, but I don't have the time to dig into their code more in detail. I think the only code that actually acts on the arrays there is the TU, and that TU always uses the extended array defintion. User code only sees pointers to that stuff, but all modifications are made through the effective type.

Comment: Writing to `array` sets its effective type to `GRealArray` which stays of that type. The effective type doesn't change if you read from that object. If at any point user reads from the struct members (using the returned type `GArray`) it is ub. If the pointer is only passed to function which use the correct type and the user never reads from the members then the code is valid. I didn't see the entire code, but I believe the intention is to have the user read from those two  members (otherwise the function could simply return an opaque pointer and avoid this issue altogether).

Comment: @2501, you are probably right, that this is meant that user code reads some of the fields. But don't mistify UB. It is just *undefined*, that is not defined by the C standard what happens. Platforms can give different guarantees, and it seems that they do. Also effectively, the user code has no way to know that the write was with a different effective type, nor can the TU here see that somebody peaked into the data by using a different type. All of this could change if this is used with LTO, that is one TU would know in some sense what the other does.

Comment: I can see your point. I probably wouldn't have had any objections if the answer included what you wrote in the last comment, as the question is about C11, not a specific platform.

Comment: @2501, as I said the question is about C11 rules for strict aliasing, and my answer was about that :)

Comment: As I understand it the answer disagrees with the conclusion I made in the comments, the behavior is undefined. That is my reasoning as to why I have to downvote the answer.

Comment: @2501, I never say that the behavior is defined, and everybody is free to dig into the comments. You might even improve the answer if you wish, or even downvote it, as you say.

Comment: I don't think the authors of the Standard intended to suggest that quality compilers should "enforce" the aliasing rules in situations that don't actually involve aliasing.  Compilers like gcc and clang that aggressively try to offer minimally-conforming (poor quality) semantics, however, *may use the rules to justify introducing aliasing in cases where none existed*.